# How to prevent programs from creating firewall rules

Tags: windows, firewall, configure

I configured firewall for blocking all non-vpn traffic (VPN client only allowed), but some programs automatically create rules to allow all their connections. Can I configure group policy or something else to prevent this actions without creating restricted user account or running programs only with user permissions?

Comment: I would use an outbound firewall to prevent them from going out>>>>>https://binisoft.org/wfc

Comment: Hi, may I ask what specific applications are creating the firewall rules? Have you ever tried to add these applications to the outbound rule of windows defender?

Comment: @GloriaGu, P2P clients and some browsers. I have already solved the problem by configuring default actions and writing a small script to disable rules that not created by me. But... I also saw something interesting while writing the script: some rules are not displayed by filtering `Get-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -Enabled True | Where-Object { $_.Profile -match "Any" } | Select-Object Name,DisplayName` but they are displayed in Windows Firewall GUI.

Comment: @GloriaGu You can take a look at it yourself in your system, and you will be surprised. Microsoft doesn't want these services to be managed using automation tools. But I have not tried to code it using .NET yet, no time for this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no.

In order to alter the firewall, you need administrative permissions. By running such program as admin, they can literally do anything and it can circumvent any restriction you put on. In order to not allow them to change it, make sure the program does not run as administrator.

If that is not an option, look into the settings for anything that automatically sets the firewall rules. If you cannot find it, contact the developer, they then need to alter the program.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post new question about kill-switch realization and try to do it different way, I think it may be a solution of priority problem with IP leaks.